# C++: Copying to dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++, copy, pointers

I currently have a weird problem with a program segfaulting but im not able to spot the error. I think the problem boils down to this.

```
struct S {int a; vector<sometype> b;}
S s1;
// fill stuff into a and b
S* s2 = new S();
*s2 = s1;
```

Could it be that the final copying is illegal in some way? Im really confused right now...
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve by doing this.

Comment: yes Daniel, i have to rework some ill designed lib :(

Comment: Sorry for deleting comment. I was saying that the code is ugly, but incomplete.

Comment: @ viswanathan What should he explain? It's perfectly common C++ code.

Comment: @swegi He _is_ using the instance created. If he had written "S* s2;" or "S* s2 = NULL;", then next line's "*s2=..." would be undefined behaviour. With the current code, the *s2 is an instance of type S which was created with "new S();".

Comment: The code works fine on my machine, the code looks correct and should not crash. @Daniel Daranas You're right.

Comment: Do you get the same error if s2 is not a pointer? i.e. `S s2; s2=s1`. If not, it's not related with the assignment to a dereferenced pointer

Answer (score 2):

You will get this behaviour if `sometype` has a bug in its user defined copy constructor and/or assignment operator. The code you have supplied is perfectly legal.

Comment: actually sometype is a shared_ptr with proper copyctr and assop

Comment: @bbb Then the bug is probably in the class the shared pointer is pointing to - possibly in its destructor. You need to post a complete example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: thx for your response. i was able to switch to boost::shared_ptr and it seems to make the problem go away (was using custom shptr-impl before).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the code looks just fine to me, unless something evil is hidden under 'sometype'